# typing a phrase and printing a list at anytime in a function

Tags: python, python-3.9

in my function I want to be able to print the following list:

toppings = ["ONION, TOMATO, GREEN PEPPER, MUSHROOM, OLIVE, SPINACH"]

at any time just by typing "X" at any point in my code

Comment: Great idea. What code are you having trouble with?

Comment: toppings = ["ONION, TOMATO, GREEN PEPPER, MUSHROOM, OLIVE, SPINACH"]

def chooseToppings():
    print("Type in one of our toppings and add it to your pizza. To see the full list of toppings, enter 'X'.")
# I want to be able to type "x" and have the list be printed

Comment: Try using the *input()* function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `input()` in a `while True:` loop to get the topping input or the `X` input.

```
toppings = ["ONION, TOMATO, GREEN PEPPER, MUSHROOM, OLIVE, SPINACH"] 
added_toppings = []

def chooseToppings(): 
    print("Type in one of our toppings and add it to your pizza. To see the full list of toppings, enter 'X'.") 
    while True:
        x = input()
        if x == "X":
            print(toppings)
        if x == "ONION":
            added_toppings.append("ONION")
        if x == "TOMATO":
            added_toppings.append("TOMATO")
        if x == "GREEN PEPPER":
            added_toppings.append("GREEN PEPPER")
        if x == "MUSHROOM":
            added_toppings.append("MUSHROOM")
        if x == "OLIVE":
            added_toppings.append("OLIVE")
        if x == "SPINACH":
            added_toppings.append("SPINACH")
        if x == "quit":
            break   
    print(added_toppings)

chooseToppings()
```

It checks every iteration for your input.

If `input = "X"` it prints the list of toppings.

If `input = "TOMATO"` it adds `"TOMATO"` to the `added_toppings` list.

If `input = "quit"` it breaks the loop and prints the `added_toppings` list.